# Output a set of random tweets without retweets mongodb

Tags: mongodb, twitter

**goal:** eliminate retweets `RT` while outputting a random set of tweets

The following code outputs 20 random tweets:

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 20
db.mycollection.aggregate({$sample: {size: 20}}, {$project: {"_id": 0,"text": 1}})
```

The following code eliminates retweets:

```
db.mycollection.find({text:{$nin:[/^RT /]}},{text:1, _id:0})
```

**question:** Is there a way to add `text:{$nin:[/^RT /]` to `db.mycollection.aggregate`code to eliminate retweets `RT` and generate a given number of random tweets? if not, what line of code will allow me to do so?

Comment: Add  `$match` as first stage in aggregate pipeline. `{$match:{text:{$nin:[/^RT /]}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Veeram's comment:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({$match:{text:{$nin:[/^RT /]}}},{$sample: {size: 20}}, {$project: {"_id": 0,"text": 1}})
```